# parse error in the following php code

Tags: php

while using the below code i am getting error like this
Parse error: in C:\wamp\www\magento3\app\code\local\Envato\Recentproducts\Block\Recentproducts.php on line 7

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Envato/Recentproducts/Block/Recentproducts.php
class Envato_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
  public function getRecentProducts() {
    // call model to fetch data
    $arr_products = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")­>getRecentProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
      $arr_products[] = array(
        'id' => $product->getId(),
        'name' => $product­>getName(),
        'url' => $product­>getProductUrl(),
      );
    }

    return $arr_products;
  }
}
```

Comment: Look *really* close at that line. Character by character.

Comment: Double check your code. It looks like you've some unicode happening here or some unrecognizable characters.

Comment: which editor are you using to code with?

Comment: You have `>` instead of `->` before `getRecentProducts()`

Comment: in my code -> is there.while posting question i just missed that one

Comment: @TimLewis For sure, but there's something rather strange happening. Details (much as I could) is in my answer below. I reopened the question.

Comment: @RajMalhotra you just edited and now there are two hyphen `)-->` please see my answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah, I see. I was just pointing out the obvious error (which I guess was typographical). That is bizarre though, I didn't realize there was another `-` character.

Comment: @TimLewis Bizarre... lordie, you're telling me. Twilight Zone stuff.

Comment: @RajMalhotra I feel that the question should be rolled back to the original post. I will do that now, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be some type of hyphens that looks like a regular `-` but isn't.

I tried to figure out which character that is, but was unable to.

I have replaced all of those with my keyboard `-`.

**Sidenote:** Something rather strange is happening here. Your code is not showing the missing hyphens, but when I copy/pasted it, they appeared in my editor.

If you go into Stack's "edit mode" for it [see for yourself-as per original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32119676/edit/b765a606-21ca-413c-adfe-429fbd1d8999), the hyphens are there.

- Can someone explain this? I couldn't figure it out. (Twilight Zone).

Here is a rewrite, this should work.

**Important:** (Copy/paste the code below, do not edit your existing code)

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Envato/Recentproducts/Block/Recentproducts.php
class Envato_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
  public function getRecentProducts() {
    // call model to fetch data
    $arr_products = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")->getRecentProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
      $arr_products[] = array(
        'id' => $product->getId(),
        'name' => $product->getName(),
        'url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
      );
    }

    return $arr_products;
  }
}
```

---

Another strange thing; hyphens are not showing in edit mode and show up as

```
$product>getName
$product>getProductUrl()
```

but when copied/pasted, they show up as:

```
$product->getName
$product->getProductUrl()
```

- TBH, I for one am totally baffled.
- If anyone has an explanation, please feel free to edit and/or comment.
- OP used Notepad++ as their code editor.

Comment: got it i just removed those hyphens and placed it again  from my keyboard.now it is working fine.thanks...

Comment: @RajMalhotra You're welcome Raj, I'm glad we were able to work this out, *cheers*